# Social Commerce Obox Facebook - Checkout not working

Tags: wordpress, facebook, woocommerce

I followed the step by step on the Obox plugin to install the tab on Facebook to have my WooCommerce integrated to Facebook with Social Commerce plugin, but when I go to Checkout nothing happens.

I got the SSL Certificate and I have configured WooCommerce as it needs to be with force HTTPS.

Comment: You really need to provide more information, such as what you have tried, screenshots, error messages etc.

Comment: So, I followed this documentation on Obox website, I'm using the "Custom App".

http://kb.oboxthemes.com/themedocs/social-commerce-setup-your-facebook-app/


I followed all the steps, all the other features on the shop is working fine, the products, cart, but the checkout page doesn't open. There is no message error just opens a blank page.

I saw on the Obox demo and there it doesn't work too, when you click to go to checkout they redirect you to their website, and I can't do it either.